# How to automatically click more than 1 button with the same CLASS on page load with Javascript

Tags: javascript, zendesk

I am currently editing my Categories page on Zendesk. Zendesk only populates 6 articles per section on the categories page with a **SEE ALL** button that takes you to the sections page and there is no way that I found to change this.

I only found a work around using javascript which populates all of the articles on the Categories page after clicking the **SEE ALL** button rather than leaving the page and going to the sections page.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /**
  @add your hc domain here
  @for eg: var hc_url = 'https://testcompany.com'
  */
  var hc_url = 'Your_HC_URL'

  var _allarticles = [],
    _sorted = [],
    _artHtml = '',
    _id,
    _url;

  var _articles = function(article) {
    $.ajax({
      url: _url,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: article
    });
  };

  // function for see all articles button in category
  $('.see-all-articles').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    _id = $(e.target).attr('href').split('/sections/')[1].split('-')[0];

    if (typeof HelpCenter.user.locale == 'undefined') {
      HelpCenter.user.locale = window.location.pathname.replace('/', '').replace('?', '/').split('/')[1];
    }

    _url = hc_url + '/api/v2/help_center/' + HelpCenter.user.locale + '/sections/' + _id + '/articles.json';
    _articles(function(data) {
      _allarticles = data.articles;

      if (data.count > 30) {
        for (var i = 1; i < data.page_count; i++) {
          _url = data.next_page;
          _articles(function(data) {
            _allarticles = _allarticles.concat(data.articles);
            _arthtml = '';
            $(_allarticles).each(function(idx, itm) {
              if (itm.draft == true) {} else {
                _arthtml = _arthtml + '<li class="' + (itm.promoted == true ? 'article-promoted' : '') + '"><span data-title="Promoted article" style="' + (itm.promoted == false ? 'display:none' : '') + '">★</span><a href="' + itm.html_url + '">' + itm.title + '</a></li>';
              }
            });
            $(e.target).parent().find('ul.article-list').html(_arthtml);
            $(e.target).hide();
          })
        }
      } else {
        _arthtml = '';
        $(data.articles).each(function(idx, itm) {
          if (itm.draft == true) {} else {
            _arthtml = _arthtml + '<li class="' + (itm.promoted == true ? 'article-promoted' : '') + '"><span data-title="Promoted article" style="' + (itm.promoted == false ? 'display:none' : '') + '">★</span><a href="' + itm.html_url + '">' + itm.title + '</a></li>';
          }
        });
        $(e.target).parent().find('ul.article-list').html(_arthtml);
        $(e.target).hide();
      }

    });
  });
  // function for see all articles button in category ends here
});
```

Now, I still want the articles to all show without a button there. I want to know if there is a way to have all of these buttons that have the same CLASS to be clicked on page load automatically.

Please help.

Comment: Repeating ids is making invalid html by web standards.  Change your ids to classes instead before further development.

Comment: ID has  to be unique

Comment: @Taplar Got it, now they all have the same class. What do I do from here?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.yourClass').forEach(element => ...do what you want... )`

Comment: An `HTMLCollection` doesn't have a method `forEach`. But you can convert it to an array so you can do `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.yourClass')).forEach(element => { /* do something with element here */ })` or you can call arrays' `forEach` on it directly using `Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.yourClass'), element => { /*...*/ })`